# Simultaneously Insert $_POST and $_FILES data In mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have a confusion and I am not able to do this task.

I wanted to insert text from `$_POST` and images from `$_FILES` simultaneously in mysql db In following order.

```
TEXT (1)
IMAGE (2)
TEXT (3)
TEXT (4)
IMAGE (5)
```

For getting this output I named every input as 1,2,3, and so on for getting considered in an order.

```
<input type="text" name="1">
<input type="file" name="2">
<input type="text" name="3">
<input type="text" name="4">
<input type="file" name="5">
```

Now I have applied loop to manually encounter each input. But I think that's useless because I can only apply loop on either `$_POST` or `$_FILES` at a time. And ultimately I get output as

```
//If I consider POST DATA first

TEXT (1)
TEXT (3)
TEXT (4)
IMAGE (2)
IMAGE (5)



//If I consider FILES DATA first
IMAGE (2)
IMAGE (5)
TEXT (1)
TEXT (2)
TEXT(4)

/
```

how do I perform this task?
Can Anyone help?

Comment: You now need to write a query with the datas you got

Comment: Do you mean, I now sort this data by putting 1,2,3,4, etc on tags??

Comment: *Why* do you need to insert in a specific order? And why are you storing images in your database and not in the filesystem, with a link in the databae?

Comment: _"I named every input as 1,2,3, and so on"_ - so you need a dynamic solution, because this could be extended to a lot more fields? Then get the maximum key out of both $_POST and $_FILES first (or send the number via an additional hidden field directly), and then use a `for` loop from 1 to x. Use `isset` to check whether `$_POST[loop index]` exists, if not you have to look in $_FILES instead.

Comment: Or, insert additional hidden fields, with a specific keyword - like `<input type="hidden" name="2" value="has-file">`. Then when you loop over $_POST and encounter that value, you know that you will have to look into $_FILES under that same name. (Not sure if parameter name collision applies between $_POST and $_FILES as well; but it might be a good idea to not name the fields with just a number to begin with; rather something like `name="text[1]"`, `name="file[1]"`, to separate this a bit better from other POST data like a submit button or similar.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, upload your files to the destination folder using PHP native function `move_uploaded_file()` and store the name of each file in an array & then store your text and images name in your Database.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST)){
      $data = $_POST;
      $files = $_FILES;
      $images_name = array();
      //loop through the $files array and store them in your destination folder
      //and store name of each file in $images_name;
      //then store your data and files name in the database
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```php
$data = $_POST + $_FILES;
ksort($data);
```

It will merge arrays preserving keys and then sort the resulting array by keys.